# How to join a data frame on top of another without changing values using Tidyverse

Tags: r, join, data-wrangling

I am working a multiple `data.frames` that I have to join on top of each other, which is kind of what I would expect from the function `full_join` of `tidyverse` to illustrate I have the following datasets

```
name<-c("AAA","AAA","AAA")
value<-c(1:3)
tag<-c(0,0,0)

part_a<-data.frame(name,value,tag)

name<-c("AAA","AAA","AAA")
value<-c(1:3)
key<-c(1,1,1)

part_b<-data.frame(name,value,key)
```

My desired output would be something like this:

| name | value | tag | key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | 0 | NA |
| AAA | 2 | 0 | NA |
| AAA | 3 | 0 | NA |
| AAA | 1 | NA | 1 |
| AAA | 2 | NA | 1 |
| AAA | 3 | NA | 1 |

but instead I am getting this:

```
> full_join(part_a,part_b)
Joining, by = c("name", "value")
  name value tag key
1  AAA     1   0   1
2  AAA     2   0   1
3  AAA     3   0   1
```

Which is very confusing to me as I think this function is trying to find common values and then aggreate the rest of the data but what I really want is just to put all `dataframes` on top of each other including the columns that they do not have in common, I know I cannot use `rbind` since this function requires dataframes to have the same column names, I would be so thankfull if you guys can help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`full_join()` is merging your data frames. Since you didn't specify the columns to use as identifiers, it's using the common fields (i.e., `name` and `value`).  To simply combine data frames you can use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows()`:

`result <- bind_rows(part_a, part_b)`

Note that there's also a `bind_cols()` for combining variables (i.e., columns) from multiple data frames into a single one.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
part_a |> bind_rows(part_b)

  name value tag key
1  AAA     1   0  NA
2  AAA     2   0  NA
3  AAA     3   0  NA
4  AAA     1  NA   1
5  AAA     2  NA   1
6  AAA     3  NA   1
```